# Work online with textmate save files to server AND local to save them in SVN

Tags: macos, svn, ftp, textmate

I work directly on a remote (S)FTP Server some times. I use textmate as editor and Transmit 4 as FTP-Client.

My Problem is, I will work live on the server and if I save files to the server I will a local copy in a special folder to save the changes to SVN.

As long as I worked with Windows, I used Notepad++ with the FTP Plugin and could say "Save local and remote".

Has any body a idear how I can do it with mac, textate and transmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your are doing web development, revert the process:

1. make a local copy of what is on your remote server
2. edit locally with your preferred editor
3. test locally
4. publish your changes to the remote server either with FTP (meh) or SVN (better)

Comment: Hi, in a normal way this is the right way. But it is a complex system (a Drupal installation with >10 sites on the installation) and I will only edit the frontend. And for security reasons I have no permissions to the databas.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Forget step 3 if you can't test locally. Just download the whole thing to your computer, put it under version control and either set Transmit up so that it syncs your local and remote files automatically on change (if that's possible, Panic's site is good looking but hopelessly light on actual information) or hit the Sync button. Do that until you are satisfied and commit your changes.

Comment: Hi, thx again. The option with the auto sync is good. But did it work, with more than one worker? What if my workmate change some stuff online, and checked it in to SVN. Ich check it out and it has a different change time than the online one? So the sync wil work again?

Comment: First let's be clear: I have no idea if Transmit does automatic syncing or not. If it does, that's less clicking for you which is good. Whether you do it automatically or manually, uploading via FTP will overwrite what's on the server no matter how many people are working on a particular file leading to all kinds of troubles. Frankly, this system is awful and should be replaced by a more solid one involving only SVN or Git or whatever VCS AND local testing.